# Self-reference a meta ID from one row to the ID in another row and populate textbox with the associated lookup

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I have a table, luDiatomTaxon, in my Access database that is the recordsource for a form. The table has the following columns: ID, ScientificName, AcceptedTaxonID, Genus, Species, etc.

Sometimes the ScientificName that has been entered in data is not the ACCEPTED ScientificName, due to differences in how labs list species or variances that exist in species by region, i.e., the ScientificName, as provided by the lab, may have verbiage added on the end to differentiate the region-specific characteristics of the identified species. However, for statistical purposes, the region-specific variances are not used when updated to a national database.

For that reason, if there is an entry in the AcceptedTaxonID field, it is referencing an ID for a different row, in the same table, that has the ACCEPTED ScientificName.

I need to write code that will--when a user selects a ScientificName, in a combox in a form, and there is an AcceptedTaxonID in the table for that row-- find the ID that matches the AcceptedTaxonID and populate a textbox with the ScientificName for that ID.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Use a DLOOKUP to get the value but I'd also think about the design of the DB - putting separate sets of info in the same table causes all sorts of problems, you need to "normalise" the DB (search that term online).

Comment: Hi Absinthe. I tried DLookup but apparently I'm not using it correctly since it's not working. I have the following code in the AfterUpdate event for the combobox:

Comment: If Not IsNull(AcceptedTaxonID) Then
        Me.txtAcceptedTaxon.Value = DLookup("[ScientificName]", "[luDiatomTaxon]", "ID = " & AcceptedTaxonID)
    End If  

Btw, I don't have a choice in using a different table. That is how I started off but then was told it needed to be a field that self-references the same table.

Comment: Try your criteria in a string: DLookup("[ScientificName]", "[luDiatomTaxon]", "ID = '" & AcceptedTaxonID & "'")

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a DLookup within a DLookup. Also, I needed to put it within an IIF statement--with a DLookup for the "expression" part of the IIF function--as I needed to instruct what was to happen if the DLookup results were Null (false). The following is the Control Source for the Accepted Taxon Scientific Name text box. When the user chooses "their" Scientific Name from a combobox, the following statement, for the text box, uses what is selected to find and display the "Accepted" Scientific Name, if one exists that is different from the selected one.

=IIf(Not IsNull(DLookUp("AcceptedTaxonID","luDiatomTaxon","ID = " & [cboDiatomTaxon])),DLookUp("ScientificName","luDiatomTaxon","ID = " & DLookUp("AcceptedTaxonID","luDiatomTaxon","ID = " & [cboDiatomTaxon])),Null)